# How to read `function type` in [dcl.fct] section

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The normative definition for `function type` is described as
[[dcl.fct#3]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.fct#3)

> A type of either form is a function type.

My reading for **these forms** are

> The type of the declarator-id in D is:
>
> > 1. **derived-declarator-type-list** noexcept <sub>opt</sub> function of parameter-type-list cv-qualifier-seq <sub>opt</sub> ref-qualifier <sub>opt</sub> returning T
> > 2. **derived-declarator-type-list** noexcept <sub>opt</sub> function of parameter-type-list cv-qualifier-seq <sub>opt</sub> ref-qualifier <sub>opt</sub> returning U

If I understand correctly, Only the **derived-declarator-type-list** is empty will the type of the declarator-id in D be the **function type**.

However, the relevant rule is not clear here. Such as, if `derived-declarator-type-list` is `pointer to`, the type of the declarator-id in D should be called a pointer type, Isn't it? So, I wonder Is it vague here for the definition of **function type**? If I misunderstand the relevant wording, please point out how to read the wording?